# Woocommerce Product Creation Automation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to develop a program that creates woocommerce products based on the media that were uploaded in the wordpress library.

All products have the same settings, the only things that change is the photo and the download.

With some research I managed to develop the following code that is running in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'product_automation');

function product_automation() {
  $loopProdutos = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  ]);
  $arrayProduct = (array) $loopProdutos->posts;
  // Picking up all the products from the store

  $idImgProduct = [];
  foreach($arrayProduct as $product) {
    $produto = wc_get_product($product->ID);
    $idImgProduct[] = $produto->image_id;
  }
  // Taking all photo IDs from existing products

  $loopImagens = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
  ]);
  $arrayImg = (array) $loopImagens->posts;
  // Taking all uploaded photos

  $idImg = [];
  foreach($arrayImg as $image) {
    $idImg[] = $image->ID;
  }
  // Getting all uploaded photo IDs

  $newIds = array_diff($idImg, $idImgProduct);
  // Seeing which IDs do not yet exist

  $newProductsArray = [];
  // Array with new products

  foreach($newIds as $idImagem) {
    $objProduct = new WC_Product_Simple();
    $objProduct->set_name("Foto");
    $objProduct->set_status("publish"); 
    $objProduct->set_catalog_visibility('visible');
    $objProduct->set_price(15.00);
    $objProduct->set_regular_price(15.00);
    $objProduct->set_sold_individually(true);
    $objProduct->set_image_id($idImagem);
    $objProduct->set_downloadable(true);
    $objProduct->set_virtual(true);
    // Create a simple product
    
    $src_img  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $idImagem, 'full');
    $img_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $idImagem, false );
    
    $file_title = $img_meta['image_meta']['title'];
    $file_url   = reset($src_img);
    $file_md5   = md5($file_url);
    
    $download  = new WC_Product_Download();
    
    $download->set_name($file_title);
    $download->set_id($file_md5);
    $download->set_file($file_url);
    
    $downloads[$md5_num] = $download;
    
    $objProduct->set_downloads($downloads);
    // Code to automatically add download link to product

    $newProductsArray[] = $objProduct;
  }

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($newProductsArray); $i++) {
    $newProductsArray[$i]->save();
  }
  //Loop to save each new product
}
```

The code works great. The problem is that it creates more products than anticipated.

For example, if I have 10 photos in my library, it creates 16 or 20 products (each photo generates more than one product).

I cannot find the error. Need help.

Comment: "init" runs everytime you load a WP page, so it could be this code runs many times while you view the site. In regard to performance, if you had 1000s of products and 1000s if images, it will also crash your site. You need to rethink your code and, in my view, only run it once, and only when a new image is uploaded. Would that suit?

Comment: Yes, that could work. Posting a code solution below (give me a few mins)

Comment: Absolutely @businessbloomer! Do you have any idea how I can do this? I searched for some hooks and found this one: wp_handle_upload. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I've tested it and it seems to work, apart from "attaching the image to the post" (I mean, it shows as product featured image, but under Media it says it's not attached to anything and you can't "detach").

I found another hook, which should work better than wp_handle_upload, and also fixed a couple of bugs (image title and downloads array):

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'bbloomer_product_automation', 9999 );

function bbloomer_product_automation( $image_id ) { 
    $product = new WC_Product_Simple();
    $product->set_name( 'Foto' );
    $product->set_status( 'publish' ); 
    $product->set_catalog_visibility( 'visible' );
    $product->set_price( 15 );
    $product->set_regular_price( 15 );
    $product->set_sold_individually( true );
    $product->set_image_id( $image_id );
    $product->set_downloadable( true );
    $product->set_virtual( true );      
    $src_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
    $file_title = get_the_title( $image_id ); // CORRECT GET IMAGE TITLE
    $file_url = reset( $src_img );
    $file_md5 = md5( $file_url );
    $download = new WC_Product_Download();
    $download->set_name( $file_title );
    $download->set_id( $file_md5 );
    $download->set_file( $file_url );
    $downloads[$file_md5] = $download; // BUG FIXED
    $product->set_downloads( $downloads );
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: It worked very very well! Thank you very much!
With this code I can upload a lot of photos and automate hours of work!